# No make target "uImage" with Buildroot 2013.05

Tags: linux-kernel, make, images, buildroot

After enabling Linux Kernel option and setting the Kernel binary format to uImage, I always get the following error:

```
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `uImage'.  Stop.
```

My buildroot configuration is almost the default one.

Any idea why it doesn't work anymore? (in an older revision it worked without errors)

Comment: This question would work much better on the Buildroot mailing list. http://buildroot.net/lists.html

Answer (score -1):

```
cd /usr/bin
cp /home/xxxx/u-boot/tools/mkimage .
```

Comment: Er. Or `cp /home/xxxx/u-boot/tools/mkimage /usr/bin`, although this doesn't seem like it would help. Can you explain it some?